# uninstalling touchpad driver to use a mouse instead

Tags: laptop, drivers, synaptics-touchpad

I have a Synaptics touchpad on a Toshiba laptop but want to use a Logitech mouse instead.  Is is safe to uninstall the Synaptic driver(s) for the touchpad, or will that make it permanently unusable if I want/need to return to using the touchpad at some later time?

Comment: Why do you even want to uninstall the touchpad drivers? They shouldn't interfere with you using a mouse if you want.

Comment: The touchpad drivers seem to be interferring with the mouse's click and sensitivity settings.  Windows says I should uninstall the Synaptic drivers, but would doing so make the touchpad permanently inaccessible?

Comment: Curious. But in any case, as @DevonParsons explains below, it won't make your touchpad permanently inaccessible. It might even retain basic functionality (cursor movement and left/right buttons), but for full functionality you'll have to reinstall the Synaptics drivers.

Answer (score 0):

No, uninstalling the drivers will not make your touchpad permanently unusable. Quite likely, if you want to use it again in the future, you will have to reinstall drivers for it.

Like Indrek said, though, it's probably unnecessary. Just plug in a mouse and ignore the touchpad.